# Custom OAuth flow for my web application where oAuthClient is Mine and oAuthServer is also mine in YII2

Tags: php, mysql, oauth-2.0, yii2

I have one webapp named `abc.com` and i have another 5 webapps .
Now i want to give my 5 webapp users to feature like `Login via abc.com` as we doing with Google / facebook and all.
i am working on yii2. My abc.com ( oauth server is on yii2 ) and all 5 web application is also in `yii2`.

so how to setup this flow in yii2 ? i found this yii2 extension - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/
but doesn't have proper guide line that how to use this . 
I just setup this extension and in my site controller.

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use yii\authclient\OAuth2;
...
...
**public function actionOauthRedirect()
    {
        $oauthClient = new OAuth2();
        $url = $oauthClient->buildAuthUrl(); // Build authorization URL
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($url); // Redirect to authorization URL.
    }**?>
```

It shows me result ,
 `PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Cannot instantiate abstract class yii\authclient\OAuth2`

As OAuth2 is Abstract class so i can't create its object. so how to use this extension ? or any other extension or workflow any one have?
please give me solution to handle it from client end and as well as from server end.

Comment: can anyone help me quickly to wrap up this phase please asap ?

Comment: Did you have a look at [the docs](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/quick-start.md)?

Answer (score -1):

This will help You

Yii2 OAuth 2.0 Server
Description

This extension provides simple implementation of Oauth 2.0 specification using Yii2 framework.
Installation

The preferred way to install this extension is through composer.

To install, either run

> $ php composer.phar require conquer/oauth2 "*"

or add

> "conquer/oauth2": "*"

to the require section of your composer.json file.

To create database tables run migration command

> $ yii migrate --migrationPath=@conquer/oauth2/migrations

Full Reference...

https://github.com/borodulin/yii2-oauth2-server